# Python define elements in a list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if it is possible to define a range of elements within a list definition by list comprehension. I would like to achieve something like this as a result:

```
>> ['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c']
```

I tried this:

```
result_list = ['a', 'b', [i for i in range(3)] 'c']
```

But this yields `['a', 'b', [1, 2, 3], 'c']`

Or if i try with tuple, I get a generator object like so: `['a', 'b', <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000002C9A9E8>, 'c']`

Can it be done somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: `['a', 'b'] + [i for i in range(1,4)] + ['c']` ?

Comment: Flatten the list `list(chain.from_iterable(['a', 'b', [i for i in range(3)], 'c']))`

Comment: @khelwood: yes, this is obvious, but I must do it inside the scope of an 
 existing list definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
result_list = ['a', 'b', *[i for i in range(3)], 'c']
print(result_list)  # ['a', 'b', 0, 1, 2, 'c']
```

Comment: this is what i got 

`>>> result_list = ['a', 'b', *[i for i in range(3)], 'c']
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`

Comment: i am with python 3

Comment: @SwadhikarC You should be using `3.6`.

Comment: anyways +1 for the idea. Hope its not working in my machine!

Comment: its python 3.4.1

Comment: @SwadhikarC To be fair, the other answer also proposes the same idea.

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions of Python 3 you can use star unpacking inside the list definition:

```
result_list = ['a', 'b', *[i for i in range(3)], 'c']
print(result_list)
```

**output**

```
['a', 'b', 0, 1, 2, 'c']
```

Bear in mind that it can get messy if you mix data types inside a list. If you want a heterogeneous collection, it's generally better to use a tuple.

---

Also note that while

```
[[i for i in range(u)] for u in range(3)]
```

is valid, and will produce

```
[[], [0], [0, 1]]
```

you can't get a flattened version by doing

```
[*[i for i in range(u)] for u in range(3)]
```

---

If you're stuck on an older version of Python, your best option is to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
import itertools

src = ['a', 'b', [i for i in range(3)], 'c']
result_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(src))
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sure, but I assume the OP wants to be able to use general list comps, and they just used `[i for i in range(3)]` to keep the example simple.

Answer (score 4):

`result_list = ['a', 'b'] + [i for i in range(1, 4)] + ['c']`

Answer (score 4):

As documented in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists you can unpack lists as arguments using the * character.

So your answer would be:

```
result_list = ['a', 'b', *[i for i in range(3)], 'c']
```